# apache not working with osx 10.10 php homebrew

Tags: php, apache, homebrew, osx-yosemite

i want to use osx built-in apache with the php version from homebrew.
If I modify /etc/apache2/httpd.conf so that the homebrew php is loaded, then no site is available not even localhost.

```
LoadModule php5_module /usr/local/Cellar/php55/5.5.13/libexec/apache2/libphp5.so
```

apachectl status tells me that apache is running. It works if I use the default path.
Do you have any suggestions to solve this problem?

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem. Homebrew added

```
LoadModule php5_module local/Cellar/php56/5.6.8/libexec/apache2/libphp5.so
```

to **httpd.conf**. I changed this line to

```
LoadModule php5_module /usr/local/opt/php56/libexec/apache2/libphp5.so
```

and restart apache. It works for me

Answer (score 1):

I'm guessing `libphp5.so` from homebrew is compiled against the homebrew Apache, which may not be binary compatible with the OS X provided built-in Apache. You should probably stick to the Homebrew Apache - in fact I would suggest sticking to Homebrew for your entire stack (or using a whole different approach such as MAMP, a Vagrant box, etc.)

Answer (score 0):

As shevron already stated, you have to get rid of the built-in-apache, and brew the apache from homebrew and reinstall (or "re-brew") php then with

```
brew install -v php55 --homebrew-apxs --with-apache
```

Follow this detailled tutorial:

https://echo.co/blog/os-x-109-local-development-environment-apache-php-and-mysql-homebrew